# Why can't a neighborhood be a finite set?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Rudin defines a neighborhood as follows:

Let $X$ be a metric space endowed with a distance function $d$. A neighborhood of a point $p \in X$ is a set $N_r(p)$ consisting of all $q \in X$ such that $d(p,q) < r$ for some $r > 0$.

He later proves two facts: every neighborhood is an open set, and every finite set is closed.

But it would seem to me that a neighborhood as defined above could be finite. For example, let $X = \{1,2,3\}$ with $d(x,y) = |x-y|$ be a metric space . Consider the neighborhood around $p = 2$ of radius $0.5$, i.e.: the set of all points $q$ in $X$ such that $d(q,p)<0.5$. But the neighborhood is simply $\{2\}$. Therefore, the neighborhood is a finite set, and therefore closed. But every neighborhood is open. This is a contradiction.

So my understanding of a neighborhood is broken somehow. It has further implications: if we define $E = \{2\}$, then the $0.5$-radius neighborhood is $\{2\}$, which is a subset of $E$, which means that $2$ is an interior point of $E$. Since $2$ is the only point in $E$, all points in $E$ are interior points, and $E$ is open. But $E$ is finite, and therefore closed.

I'm probably missing something obvious. Can anyone spot my mistake?

Comment: Nothing about the definition of a set being open or closed precludes a set being both -- merely your intuition. :)

Comment: It is possible for are set to be open *and* closed, as $\{2\}$ in your example. Being open and closed isn't mutually exclusive.

Comment: "not closed" is not necessarily "open" and "not open" is not necessarily "closed": "not open" and "not closed" can both be "ajar"!

Comment: Obligatory quote: ''…an answer to the mathematician’s riddle: “How is a set different from a door?” should be: “A door must be either open or closed, and cannot be both, while a set can be open, or closed, or both, or neither!”'' - Munkres

Comment: Well, in that case, Rudin 2.21 is incorrect, unless there's another hypothesis.

Comment: @jme A nonempty finite set cannot be closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$, in the usual topology, and that is what Rudin does in 2.21.

Comment: Yes, I am just realizing that he wrote in $\mathbb{R}^2$, my mistake. So the takeaway is that $\{2\}$ is open and closed in the topology I defined above, but closed in the usual topology.

Comment: @jme: I wonder if it's understood in Rudin 2.21 (I don't have the book so I can't say for you) that the metric space you're working with is one such as $\mathbb{R}^n$ or something similar; in that case it *is* true that every non-empty finite set is closed and not open, since every non-empty open set is infinite in a dense metric space. See my answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Every finite set is closed" does not imply "every open neighbourhood is infinite".

Let $(X,d)$ be any metric space, and let $F \subseteq X$ be a non-empty finite subset; say $F = \{ x_1, \cdots, x_n \}$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$. To prove that $F$ is closed it suffices to prove that $X - F$ is open. So let $p \in X-F$. Then the set $\{ d(p,x_1), \cdots, d(p,x_n) \}$ has a minimum value, say $\delta$, and we know that $\delta > 0$ since $p \not \in F$, and so whenever $d(p,q) < \delta$ we have $q \in X-F$. But this tells you that the (open) ball of radius $\delta$ about $p$ lies in $X-F$, and hence $X-F$ is open.

In your examples, yes, the sets are *open and finite*, but they are also *closed*!

The key fact to take home is that sets are allowed to be both open and closed.

---

However, there is a partial converse: in a *dense* metric space, every open neighbourhood is infinite.

A metric space $(X,d)$ is *dense* if for any $x \in X$ and $r > 0$ there exists $y \in X$ with $x \ne y$ and $d(x,y) < r$ $-$ that is, given any point in the space, there are other points which lie arbitrarily close to that point. $\mathbb{R}$ is a dense space, so is $\mathbb{Q}$, so is $(0,1)$, and indeed so is any other non-empty open subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

The fact that open neighbourhoods in dense metric spaces are necessarily infinite is clear from the definition. [It's also clear that a metric space in which every open neighbourhood is infinite is dense, and so the two conditions are equivalent.]

Comment: This makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For an interesting example, let $X$ be any non-empty set, and define $d:X\times X\to\Bbb R$ by $$d(x,y)=\begin{cases}0 & x=y\\1 & x\neq y.\end{cases}$$ This can be shown to be a metric on $X$ (called the *discrete metric*). One interesting property is that in the metric space $(X,d)$, **every** subset of $X$ is **both open and closed**. Even in general metric spaces, there will always be at least two subsets that are both open and closed--namely, the empty set and the whole set.